# Schema setup for a relationship counting system (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, mongoose

I am trying to see how frequently items (in a shopping cart) appear together. So if a customer buys `item1` and `item2`, it has a count of 1. If another customer buys `item1`, `item2`, and `item3` then the `item1-item2` count should become 2 and the `item1-item2-item3` count should become 1.

I understand it will become VERY large, but that's okay. Once the data is built up, there won't be many writes, but there will be a TON of reads. I'm using node.js with mongoose, if that matters.

Comment: I'd suggest you consider another DB as this won't be something MongoDB is particularly good at storing. A graph database may be a better fit for storage, and for queries. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn313282.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example of 150 items in a set, the number of combinations you would have to store a counter for would be [1427247692705959881058285969449495136382746473](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20150%20choose%20n,%20n%20from%202%20to%20150). You might want to stick to just storing pairs if you want to make this general-purpose :)